# PDO::beginTransaction() and foreign key violation in sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, foreign-keys

I'll use the example from [SQLite help page](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) about foreign key constrains:

Let's build 2 tables in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE artist(
  artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  artistname  TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE track(
  trackid     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  trackname   TEXT, 
  trackartist INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT fk
  FOREIGN KEY(trackartist) REFERENCES artist(artistid))
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Let's add 2 records from SQLite command:

```
sqlite> pragma foreign_keys = ON;
sqlite> INSERT INTO artist(artistid, artistname) VALUES(null, 'Bing Crosby');
sqlite> INSERT INTO track(trackid, trackname, trackartist) VALUES(null, 'White Christmas', 1);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM artist;
1|Bing Crosby
sqlite> SELECT * FROM track;
1|White Christmas|1
```

Now, while the command tool does **NOT** allow (**correctly**) an insert of:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO track(trackid, trackname, trackartist) VALUES(null, 'Another Track', 9);
Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

php on the other hand **DOES** allow (**incorrectly**) this:

```
$dbh = new \PDO('sqlite:test.sq3');
$dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
   if (!$dbh->beginTransaction())
      throw new \Exception('Could not started a transaction!');
   //$dbh->exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;');
   $query = $dbh->prepare('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;');
   $query->execute();
   //$dbh->exec("INSERT INTO track(trackid, trackname, trackartist) VALUES(null, 'Another Track', 9);");
   $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO track(trackid, trackname, trackartist) VALUES(null, 'White Christmas', 9);");
   $query->execute();
   $dbh->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   $dbh->rollback();
}
```

See the violation:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM track;
1|White Christmas|1
2|Another Track|9
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: Read the row returned by the statement `PRAGMA foreign_keys`. Was it actually enabled?

Comment: Ok, `$query->execute()` returns 1 (?!)

Comment: sqlite version 3.11.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: To read the returned row(s), you must call `fetchAll()`.

Comment: For the PRAGMA `$query`: `error_log(print_r($query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), true));` I have just `Array()` in the log file

Comment: Which PRAGMA, `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` or `PRAGMA foreign_keys`?

Comment: for `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` I added after `execute()` the afore mentioned `error_log()`. If I test it on `PRAGMA foreign keys;` my log is: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [foreign_keys] => 0
        )

)

Comment: Ok, suppose I first set `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON` and *then* I make a query of `PRAGMA foreign_keys` to see what is going on the result is `Array([0] => Array([foreign_keys] => 0))` which means it didn't set! Back to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) says:

> This pragma is a no-op within a transaction; foreign key constraint enforcement may only be enabled or disabled when there is no pending BEGIN or SAVEPOINT.

Comment: Of course I don't understand what `no-op` means in English! As a term in a legal document could easily lock me in jail! But I finally found it! just write one simple line `$dbh->exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys = 1;');` ***before*** `$dbh->beginTransaction()` and you're set!!!